# How to sort an array of hashes with multiple keys in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a reference to a list of hashes in Perl, like this:

```
my $students = [
    { name => "Johnson", age => 19, gpa => 2.5, major => "CS" },
    { name => "Jones", age => 18, gpa => 2.0, major => "IT" },
    { name => "Brown", age => 19, gpa => 2.2, major => "SE" }
];
```

I need to sort this list ascending and descending by the `name` key. I know about the Perl `sort` function, but this is a little confusing to me with hashes and multiple keys.

I'm trying this (going off of other questions I've seen on SO):

```
foreach my $key (sort {$%students->{name}}) {
    print $students{$key} . "\n";
}
```

But it's not quite there (getting syntax errors).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with `$key` like that, because you have an array(ref), not a hash(ref) in `$students`. (And each element of the array is a hash reference).

When you `sort` you iterate an list of values comparing elements (e.g. each element of an array, or each key returned by `keys %hash`) - each element in turn is assigned to `$a` and `$b` and compared. If you specify a custom sort, it should return negative, zero or positive based on relative position of elements.

The 'default' is:

```
sort { $a cmp $b } @list;
```

Which compares alphanumerically and `cmp` returns `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on relative ordering. (For numeric comparison we would use `$a <=> $b`).  We need to iterate the elements of your array (ref) and then compare them by extracting a suitable comparison value.

So:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $students = [
    { name => "Johnson", age => 19, gpa => 2.5, major => "CS" },
    { name => "Jones", age => 18, gpa => 2.0, major => "IT" },
    { name => "Brown", age => 19, gpa => 2.2, major => "SE" }
];

foreach my $hashref ( sort { $a -> {name} cmp $b -> {name} } @$students ) {
    print $hashref -> {name},"\n";
}
```

Comment: @DavidMordigal If you find a answer that suits your needs you should accept it :-)